# Select2 widget for ManyToMany relationship

Tags: python, django, django-forms, jquery-select2

I am using [django-select2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) widgets to get a nicer `ManyToMany` widget. The view looks nicer and I can search and select many different users. However, when I save the model, the list of allowed users is blank. I tried this direct from the view and from a unit tests. I cannot fathom what I am doing wrong.

*Any idea?*

I strongly suspect there are two problems: One in the saving of the form created model and another one is how I set the `data` dictionary values.

---

My Model:

```
class ProjectCode(models.Model):
    allowed_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

---

My Form:

```
class ProjectCodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectCode
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'allowed_users': Select2MultipleWidget(), }
```

---

My View:

```
def create_code(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new = form.save(commit=False)
            new.save()
    form = ProjectCodeForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'order_book/create_code.html', context)
```

---

My Test:

```
def test_code_create_post_pass(self):
    init = len(ProjectCode.objects.all())
    data = {'allowed_users': [self.jdoe.pk, ], }
    response = self.client.post('/order_book/code/create/', data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertContains(response, "Create a project code")
    self.assertEqual(init + 1, len(ProjectCode.objects.all()))
    self.assertEqual("jdoe", ProjectCode.objects.all()[0].display_allowed_users())
```

This tests fails with:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_code_create_post_pass (order_book.tests.AuthorisedViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/tests.py", line 385, in test_code_create_post_pass
    "jdoe", ProjectCode.objects.all()[0].display_allowed_users())
AssertionError: u'jdoe' != u''
- jdoe
+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post question, continue to play with `pdb` and an idea pops up… I modified the view to:

```
def create_code(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new = form.save(commit=False)
            # I am doing "clever" things with the new object here,
            # like setting a creator and created date/time…
            new.save()
            for usr in form.cleaned_data['allowed_users']:  # ← This is NOT correct
                new.allowed_users.add(usr)  # ← Neither is this…
    form = ProjectCodeForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'order_book/create_code.html', context)
```

I was getting an error saying that `allowed_users` could not be set as `new` did not have a primary key yet. This lead me to try to set the data after having saved the object.

Note that the test `data` is correct and that the test now passes fine.

Alternatively, you could [read the freaking documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) and use the correct method `save_m2m()`:

```
def create_code(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new = form.save(commit=False)
            # I am doing "clever" things with the new object here,
            # like setting a creator and created date/time…
            new.save()
            form.save_m2m()  # ← This is CORRECT!
    form = ProjectCodeForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'order_book/create_code.html', context)
```